# SQLite.SQLiteException: no such function: tostring using LINQ query while getting CurrentDate

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I would like to get two columns like SoccerStatus, SoccerDate from the `SoccerAvailability` in SQLite database into a list where SoccerDate="Today" using LINQ query ? I have tried the below query, but its throws exception, I need CurrentDate alone, no time is needed in my query.

`List<SoccerAvailability> myList = (from x in conn.Table<SoccerAvailability>().Where(x => x.CurrentDate == DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")) select x).ToList();`

Unhandled Exception:

SQLite.SQLiteException: no such function: tostring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert the current date to a string before you execute your query

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
List<SoccerAvailability> myList = (from x in conn.Table<SoccerAvailability>().Where(x => x.CurrentDate ==  currentDate) select x).ToList();
```

Comment: Sooperb... It was happening for me when I tried to use the preference values directly. Thank you